# How to call IEnumerable function

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have this type of function . Now i dont know how to call this to get the data from fields.

```
public static IEnumerable GetMaterialSearch(int reqNo)
    {
        DataClassesCRMDataContext dbContext = new DataClassesCRMDataContext();
        try
        {
            var res = from tbl1 in dbContext.MaterialApplicants
                      join tbl2 in dbContext.MaterialRequests on tbl1.ApplicantID equals tbl2.Applicant
                      where tbl2.RCD_ID == reqNo
                      select new
                      {
                          Crusher = tbl2.Crusher,
                          ApplicantID = tbl2.Applicant,
                          Comments = tbl2.Comments,
                          ReqDate = tbl2.ReqDate,
                          Operator = tbl2.Operator,
                          Title = tbl1.Title,
                          Applicant = tbl1.Applicant,
                          Address = tbl1.Address,
                          Nationality = tbl1.Nationality,
                          HouseNo = tbl1.HouseNo,
                          MobileNo = tbl1.MobileNo,
                      };

            if (res.Count() > 0)
            {
                return res.ToList();  
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbContext.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: This `if (res.Count() > 0) { return res.ToList();  ` is wrong and will cause the query to be executed twice. Do as `var res2 = res.ToList(); return res2.Count > 0 ? res2 : null;`

Comment: You should remove that `res.Count() > 0` check as it is totally unnecessary and will just make an extra call to the database.

Comment: Somebody wrote crap code. That should select into a concrete type, not an anonymous type.

Answer (score 5):

An `IEnumerable` is a sequence typically intended to be iterated over:

```
var result = GetMaterialSearch(42);
if (result != null)
    foreach (var entry in result)
        DoSomething(entry);
```

**Edit**: As has been pointed out above, the issue with your code is that you are returning an anonymous type within your `IEnumerable` result. Anonymous types are not intended to cross method boundaries. From [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type of a method as having an anonymous type. [...] To pass an anonymous type, or a collection that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can declare the parameter as type object. However, doing this defeats the purpose of strong typing. If you must store query results or pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type.

If you absolutely do not want to create a named class, you could use reflection to access your fields, such as through the `dynamic` keyword introduced in C# 4:

```
var result = GetMaterialSearch(42);
if (result != null)
    foreach (dynamic entry in result)
        Console.WriteLine(entry.ID);
```

Comment: As long as `GetMaterialSearch` returns `IEnumerable` the `foreach` loop will return `object`, so you won't be able to get the data unless you use `dynamic` or reflection.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Correct; I've edited my post to explain that.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek This is false. There are some tricks to cast to an anomymous type, and then through the use of `var` use it, but they are ugly.

Comment: @xanatos Could you link any source about that *trick*, please? It's quite interesting.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: [Can't return anonymous type from method? Really?](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx/) However, this is just a hack that I wouldn't recommend in practice.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek See for example http://ideone.com/qWG3wS . It's based on the fact that all anonymous types with the same parameters of the same type in the same order in the same assembly are in truth a single anonymous type, so if you "recreate" them in two places, you only have a single type. Ah... clearly I think the same thing as Douglas :-) But it *is* possible. The difference between impossible and possible-but-nearly-useless :-)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Ah... and I didn't copy the code from the article linked by douglas :-) I really wrote the same code (plus the `static`) in 5 minutes, with the same parameters :-) :-)

Comment: huh, looks like it's even worse to maintain then `dynamic`...  But thanks for the sample code, I wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score 2):

Your method returns non-generic `IEnumerable` and that's the problem. You should change it to generic `IEnumerable<T>`, but it will require creating another class:

```
class MaterialItem
{
    public string Crusher { get; set; }
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    // (...)
}
```

Then change your method signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<MaterialItem> GetMaterialSearch(int reqNo)
```

And change your query to return `MaterialItem`s instead of anonymous type objects:

```
        var res = from tbl1 in dbContext.MaterialApplicants
                  join tbl2 in dbContext.MaterialRequests on tbl1.ApplicantID equals tbl2.Applicant
                  where tbl2.RCD_ID == reqNo
                  select new MaterialItem
                  {
                      Crusher = tbl2.Crusher,
                      ApplicantID = tbl2.Applicant,
                      Comments = tbl2.Comments,
                      ReqDate = tbl2.ReqDate,
                      Operator = tbl2.Operator,
                      Title = tbl1.Title,
                      Applicant = tbl1.Applicant,
                      Address = tbl1.Address,
                      Nationality = tbl1.Nationality,
                      HouseNo = tbl1.HouseNo,
                      MobileNo = tbl1.MobileNo,
                  };
```

But that's not the only change I would make. Calling `Count()` to call `ToList()` later cause unnecessary DB calls.

I would go with:

```
var results = res.ToList();
if(results.Any())
    return results;
return null;
```

Comment: `Your method returns non-generic IEnumerable` No. His problem is that he is returning an anonymous object. And you even show that he shouldn't. You can enumerate `IEnumerable` (non-generic). In .NET 1.0 - 1.1 they had only it, and they still lived with collections.

Comment: @xanatos You can enumerate it, but you can't get into it's properties any other way then using `dynamic` or reflection.

Comment: So my statement is valid. You are confusing the tree from the forest. You say `Your method returns non-generic `IEnumerable` and that's the problem` but then you admit that that isn't the problem. Even a `IEnumerable<object>` would be difficult to enumerate. The problem is in the anonymous object.

Comment: +1: This is the correct answer (apart from the imprecision pointed out by xanatos in the lead sentence).